# Column chart with primary and secondary y-axes

Tags: excel, graph, charts

My problem seems simple, I just want to make a column chart with 2 y-axes. When I do this, Excel automatically puts the columns overlapping. I do not want them overlapped! How do I go about correcting this?

An image of what is happening:

[image: Excel overlapping column problem]

Comment: have you considered a 3d plot?

Comment: I have not, but I do not want to get fancy! I would like this to be a simple 2 column graph, with two y-axes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could achieve the chart as shown below with some rather careful manipulation:

[image: SO17712980 example]

Basically is requires spacing out your data as shown in columns A:C but also right-aligning the horizontal axis labels, adjusting the secondary axis maximum (and format of both vertical axes, if necessary) and the Gap Width for Series1 to about 10% and for Series2 to about 5%.

(PS I chose the wrong value for C5.)

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing. Thank you very much for your response!

Answer (score 14):

I believe this method is more straightforward:

1. Create two dummy series. Series1 and dummy1 on the primary axis, Series2 and dummy2 on the secondary axis.
2. Reorder the series so dummy1 is above Series1
   [image]

Comment: you can also delete the 'dummy' entries from the legend, by clicking on them and pressing delete, and white text columns C and D (and even move them to another area of the workbook) to clean this up a little.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to change the secondary `Y` data's `chart-type` to a `scatter plot`. The overlap of this symbol with the bars of the primary `Y`, is the desired result. You simply right click the secondary bar and select `"Change the chart type"`, and select scatter with or without the connecting line.

Comment: Nice and simple technique compared to the other approaches...assuming the scatter plot can work of course.